# Merge (add values together, reduce to single element) all pairs in List (except for first and last pair)

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

##### Goal

Reduce the total length of a list by merging pairs in the list (**except** the first and last pair) into single elements.

##### Visual Example

I have a single dimension list, which looks somewhat like this:

| Pair (A) | Pair (B) | Pair (C) | Pair (D) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.0 | 10.0 | 19.0 | 34.0 | 16.0 | 12.0 | 99.0 | 68.0 |

An example of what I would like the list (or a new list) to look like instead:

| Pair (A) | Pair (B) | Pair (C) |
| --- | --- | --- |

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.0 | 10.0 | 53.0 | 28.0 | 99.0 | 68.0 |

Still a single dimension list but the total length has been reduced by merging pairs of elements (ignoring the first and last pair) into a single element (instead of a pair of elements), with a new value calculated by adding the former pairs values together.

##### Theory

Using some combination of `GetRange`, `Select`, `Aggregate` and `Where` to either alter the original list, or return a new list *somehow*.

##### In-closing

I'd like to apologise for the dodgy wording, and formatting of my question: I'm obviously out of my depth in what I'm trying to achieve - **any help would be greatly appreciated**.

Cheers.

Comment: And the list you start with always has an even number of pairs?

Comment: What will happen if there are 5 pairs inside the original list? What will the length of the result list be in that case?

Comment: Yes, the initial list is always an even number of pairs, with a minimum count of four (two pairs). @PharazFadaei The length of the resulting list is unimportant as long as it includes the two ignored pairs, I think I understand the point you're making though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds fairly simple to do with a loop

```
var outList = new List<int>();

outList.Add(inList[0]);
outList.Add(inList[1]);

for(int x = 2; x < inList.Count -2;x+=2){
  outList.Add(inList[x] + inList[x+1]);
}

outList.Add(inList[^2]);
outList.Add(inList[^1]);
```

You take the first two elements unchanged, you then run a loop that skips in twos summing a pair of elements together and `Add`ing the result to the outList, stopping short of processing the last 2 entries, then add those verbatim to the outList

If the intent was to modify the original list, work backwards in twos between the end and the start

```
for(int x = list.Count - 4; x >= 2;x-=2){
  list[x] += list[x+1];
  list.RemoveAt(x+1);
}
```

By working backwards, our manipulations (removing from the list) doesn't affect future elements we have yet to process as the list shortens, which makes the logic a bit easier

--

LINQ's a hammer; not every problem is a nail.. If you can only accept LINQ then it could look like:

```
list.Take(2).Concat(
  list.Skip(2)
    .Take(list.Count-4)
    .Select((e, i) => new { E = e, N = i/2 })
    .GroupBy(x => x.N, x => x.E)
    .Select(g => g.Sum())
).Concat(
  list.Skip(list.Count-2)
).ToList();
```

Or with ranges:

```
list[..2].Concat(
  list[2..^2]
    .Select((e, i) => new { E = e, N = i/2 })
    .GroupBy(x => x.N, x => x.E)
    .Select(g => g.Sum())
).Concat(
  list[^2..]
).ToList();
```

Take the first 2, add on the result of taking the middle N values, projecting them including their index and grouping on index/2 then summing the resulting group, then Concat on the last 2. I don't like it as much as the loops. I can think of other linq ways too, but none I really like.